# conda installation of peakutils.peak in python

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, conda, peakutils

I want to use

```
import peakutils.peak in python (ubuntu 16.04)
```

I use anaconda packages in python. How could I download peakutils package using conda.

I use

```
conda install -c cbetters peakutils=1.0.3
```

But the error that I got:

```
import peakutils.peak
ImportError: No module named peakutils.peak
```

Comment: have you tried `python setup.py install` ?

Comment: yeah, but it doesnot work @Gaurav

Comment: have you installed other libraries on which this package depends upon ?

Comment: And which Python version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot find a package to install with conda, then try using `pip` to install it from PyPI (the Python package Index) or from local source or even some other repository.

Since PeakUtils is available from PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PeakUtils). Here is what it looked like for me just now (UPPER/lower case does not seem to matter):

```
BarryPye@workstation ~ $ pip install peakutils
Collecting peakutils
  Downloading PeakUtils-1.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /local/Apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from peakutils)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /local/Apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from peakutils)
Building wheels for collected packages: peakutils
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for peakutils ... done
  Stored in directory: /local/BarryPye/.cache/pip/wheels/cb/17/d9/ae7f621c1e24ce2e4da18ca9f01b032f4474bb1b04822d886e
Successfully built peakutils
Installing collected packages: peakutils
Successfully installed peakutils-1.1.0
```